# disable if input value is text and enable if it number

Tags: php, html

I want :
if the value of input is text, then disable.
if the value of the same input is number ,then enable.

the code is

```
 <input type="text" value ="<?php echo $row [0];? disable>
```

Comment: There was a typo in my answer, i have updated it, please check if it works

Comment: this is probably better done in JavaScript as in most situations you want to handle this without performing the postback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will test if your value is an `int` (cases like `1.0` or `'1'` will be disabled) :

```
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $row[0];?>"<?php echo !is_int($row[0]) ? ' disabled="disabled"' : ''; ?> />
```

This will test if your value is an `float` (cases like `1` or `'1'` will be disabled) :

```
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $row[0];?>"<?php echo !is_float($row[0]) ? ' disabled="disabled"' : ''; ?> />
```

This will test if your value is an `int` or a `float` or a numeric `string` (cases like `'1'` be enabled) :

```
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $row[0];?>"<?php echo !is_numeric($row[0]) ? ' disabled="disabled"' : ''; ?> />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use JS to do this :

Here one textbox contains text as input which is disabled, and the other which contains the number is enabled.

```js
var x = document.getElementById("txtbox").value;
var y = document.getElementById("txtbox2").value;
if(isNaN(x)){
 document.getElementById("txtbox").disabled = true;
}


if(isNaN(y)){
  document.getElementById("txtbox2").disabled = true;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value ="txtbox" id="txtbox">
<input type="text" value="123" id="txtbox2">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" value ="<?php echo $row[0]; ?>" <?php if(is_numeric($row[0])) echo 'disabled="disabled"'; ?>>
```

Comment: That's the opposite of what OP is trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping your value:

```
<input type="text" value ="<?php echo $row[0]; ?>" <?php if(!is_numeric($row [0])) echo "disabled"; ?> >
```

OR

```
<input type="text" <?php if(!is_numeric($row[0])){echo 'value="'.$row[0].'" disabled';}else{echo 'value="'.$row[0].'"';} ?>>
```

Both will work. Use what you are more comfortable with.
*I hope it helps*

Comment: That's the opposite of what OP is trying to achieve. Plus, there's no need to put the `value` attribute in the `if`.

Comment: I forgot to put '!'..i have updated the answer. and i dont think there is any problem if you put value inside if, that way you can handle code better

Comment: I removed my downvote, but still I feel there's no need to put the `value` inside the `if`, as it will always be `$row[0]`. IMHO, it's harder to read and harder to maintain.

Comment: You anyway will have to use `$row[0]` two times but i gave both options.